# stop sequentialtask if a task fails

Tags: locust

I have a mobile application which works by making sequential calls to different APIs depending upon the action the user is taking.  For example,

```
1) get app specific details go to  url https://config.url with GET  
2) user login, go to url https://login.url with POST 
3)perform step 1 at url https://step.url with POST  
4) perform step 2 at url  https://step.url with  POST 
5) get file at url http://file.url with  GET
```

steps (1) and (2)  must  complete successfully before the remaining steps can execute.  How do I stop the current sequence if a mandatory step fails, without affecting other sequential tasks in operation?